# Android onclick-Method exception

Tags: android, dialog

Hello I am getting the following exception and I don't know why: **Could not find a method checkPassword(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'bPassword'**

I am using a Activtiy as Dialog. The user must type a password in the Dialog, if it is correct another activity should be called. Here is my code:

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Enter your Password:"
            android:id="@+id/dText"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/ePassword"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/bPassword"
            android:onClick="checkPassword" />


</LinearLayout>
```

My Java Class:

```
package com.example.RemindMe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DialogActivity extends Activity {

    private String password = "test";
    private EditText ePassword;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Note Activity is password protected");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dText);
        textView.setText("Message");

        dialog.show();


        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0){
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    public void checkPassword(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.bPassword:
                String pwEditText = ePassword.getText().toString();

                if(pwEditText.equals(password)){
                    //If password correct, start another activity
                startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteActivity.class));
                } else {
                    textView.setText("Wrong Password, PLS Type it again");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the password should not be used as a clear text and so on. This is only for testing purpose. I am planninng to hash and store the password in the sharedpref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give your `Activity` the appearance of a `Dialog` add the following line to the `<activity>` tag of the appropriate `Activity` in your `manifest.xml`.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

then you can remove all of the `dialog` code and it should work since your `onClick` is in the `Activity` itself and not the `Dialog`. Just don't forget to add `setContentView(...)` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: thx, your solution works fine. Also thx to all the others for the help

Answer (score 0):

you have to define which theme you want in you activity like this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Answer (score -1):

The `android:onClick="checkPassword"` is only usable for buttons used in activity, because the checkPassword method was declare in activity.

You should avoid instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use AlertDialog.

Remove that button from xml and use the ok button from AlertDialog.

Comment: But the dialog is displayed withoud a button...how can I add a button to my Dialog. I thought I can do it like using an AlertDialog (with  alert.setPositiveButton) but how can I do it on my Dialog? Do I need to pass something to the Constructor?

Comment: Wrong. You can use it on any view or dialog or a customView that is in the same context of the activity.